# How can I send integer value as JSON post value and process in express JS file?

Tags: node.js, json, ajax, express

Below is my JavaScript code. I am trying to send an ID to server.js through AJAX post as follows:

```
$("#select_link").click(function(e){

   e.preventDefault();

   console.log("link clicked..");

   var data={};

   data.id = document.getElementById("d_id").value;



   $.ajax({

     type: "POST",

     data: JSON.stringify(data),

     processData: false,

     contentType: 'application/json',

     url: 'http://localhost:3000/driverDetails',

     success: function(data){

       console.log("success:  "+JSON.stringify(data));

     }

   });

 });
```

Below is my server.js code.

```
app.post('/driverDetails', function(req, res){

  var obj = {};

  var id_driver = Number(JSON.stringify(req.body.id));

  console.log('body: '+ id_driver);

  res.send(req.body);

})
```

When I send my data as:

```
res.send(req.body)
```

I am able to see the data correctly in browser console. But ID is in string format. I want that ID in integer format in this server.js so that I can use in SQL query. How can I achieve it?  If I try to remove data and processData properties from AJAX, it will return empty object in response--it will not send anything to the server.js file, not even the string version of my ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

you can put 'Number' for 'document.getElementById("d_id").value'
in ajax func.

and you don't use 'JSON.stringify' for any where. you can use from 'bodyParser' in server.js. i used it.

I run the following code and its ok work.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="select_link">Select Link</button>
    <input type="number" id="d_id">

    <script>
      $("#select_link").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("link clicked..");
        var data = {};
        data.id = Number(document.getElementById("d_id").value);
        console.log(data);

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          data: JSON.stringify(data),
          processData: false,
          contentType: "application/json",
          url: "http://localhost:3000/driverDetails",
          success: function (data) {
            console.log("success:  " + JSON.stringify(data));
          },
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

server.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(cors({origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:8021'}));

app.post('/driverDetails', (req, res) => {
    var id_driver = Number(req.body.id);
    console.log('body: '+ id_driver);
    res.send(req.body);
})

app.listen(port, () => {console.log(`App listening at http://localhost:${port}`)})
```

Comment: I had tried this too. Thanks for the suggestion though. The quick and simple fix was not to use stringify inside my server.js file at all. I just had to replace Number(JSON.stringify(req.body.id)); with JSON.parse(req.body.id);

Answer (score 0):

Im supposing that you are getting the id on this line:

```
 data.id = document.getElementById("d_id").value;
```

So, this "d_id" input is type text? If yes, you should change it to type number. If you need to keep it as type text, you need to convert its value to Number before to perform the JSON Stringification.

```
data.id = +document.getElementById("d_id").value.trim();
```

The + prefix will coerce your string into a number, and the trim() will assure that it doesnt contains unwanted spaces. Now you're safe.

Considering the example above, if your input value is "undefined" or contains non-numerical chars, your ID will be NaN. If your input value is null, your ID will be 0.

This is because an input type text always returns a string, and data types matters to JSON. If you stringified a string, JSON.parse() will output a string, same for number. [Here Is a reference about JSON data types](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp)

There are of course other ways to cast to Number in JS like Number(), parseInt(), parseFloat(), ~~, >>>>0, etc. Its a good point to know about. Here is a cool and light reading about:

https://gomakethings.com/converting-strings-to-numbers-with-vanilla-javascript/

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But I had tried all of it. The simple and quick fix was to use JSON.parse(req.body.id); in place of Number(JSON.stringify(req.body.id));. I realized it too late that I had been doing the wrong thing.